# How to make (impolite?) suggestions like "How about you don't ..."?

Tags: cortesía

I understand that phrasing a statement like this in English is usually considered a bit impolite, I am just wondering how it is done in Spanish or if there is an equivalent?

> "How about you ..."

e.g.

> "How about you don't judge people"
>   "How about you wait until dinner time before eating..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La mejor fórmula para

> How about you (don't) `verb` ...

es una de estas:

> 1. ¿Por qué no `verbo conjugado en indicativo`... ?  
>   2. ¿No has considerado `verbo en infinitivo`... ?  
>   3. ¿Te parecería `verbo en infinitivo`... ? or ¿Te importaría `verbo en infinitivo`?

Ejemplos:

> 1. ¿Por qué no te esperas a la hora de la cena para comer?
> 2. ¿No has considerado esperarte a la cena antes de comer?
> 3. ¿Te parecería esperar a la cena antes de comer?

Puedes añadir un toque de amabilidad usando un *condicional:*

> ¿Podrías dejar de criticar/juzgar a la gente?

Y un toque de rudeza

> 1. ¿Por qué `X` no te esperas a la hora de la cena para comer?

donde

> `X=` demonios, chingados, carajo, coño, etc.

Comment: Me viene a la cabeza el incidente en que el Rey Juan Carlos de España espetó a Hugo Chávez de Venezuela el famoso: _"¿Por qué no te callas?"_

Comment: @deStrangis excelente sugerencia ;) digo, gramaticalmente.

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be

> ¿Qué tal si `oración en indicativo`?

It also has an impolite and condescending tone.

Rough translation: "How is it if you ...?"

Examples:

> 1. ¿Qué tal si dejas de juzgar a los demás?
> 2. ¿Qué tal si te esperas a la hora de cenar para comer?

Of course, the option with

> ¿Por qué no `oración en indicativo`?

is perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the same in Spanish: "¿Por qué no dejas de juzgar a la gente?" or "¿Qué tal si esperas a la cena para...". But it's all about the tone you use, I think.